# C# Exception not being handled

Tags: c#, exception

Currently working on a small project, which includes a Registry form, where users can Sign up log in. I have error providers which tell the user if the information they have entered is incorrect or not. For some reason the exceptions are no longer being handled, even though they were a while back.

Here is the code for when the user presses the 'Register Button'

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Try - Catch Statements
    //Try to set the forename 
    try
    {
        player1.Forename = txtForename.Text;
        player2.Forename = txtForename.Text;
        errForename.Icon = Properties.Resources.Correct;
        errForename.SetError(txtForename, "OK");
    }
    catch (NewException exc)
    {
        errForename.SetError(txtForename, exc.MessageM);
    }
```

It then does this for other details, e.g surname, username.

Here is the User class getters and setters

```
public string Forename
{
    get
    {
        return forename;
    }
    set
    {
        bool okChar = OnlyChars(value, "Forename");

        if (okChar == true)
            forename = value;
        else
        {
            throw new NewException(errorMessage);
            forename = null;                        
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the NewException class that I wrote

```
namespace Colludia
{
    class NewException : Exception
    {
        private string messageM;

        public NewException() : base()
        {    
        }

        public NewException(string message) : base(message)
        {
            messageM = message;    
        }

        public string MessageM
        {
            get { return messageM; }
            set { messageM = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should [not use exceptions for your normal control flow](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl). You can check easily if a string only contains characters. No exception needed. Exceptions which control flow are  like non-local goto statements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please rewrite your code as a [mcve] - also note that using auotmatically implemented properties will significantly reduce the code in your `NewException` class. Finally, how do you expect the statement after your `throw` statement to execute?

Comment: The MessageM variable in the exception class is also completely useless; it's just a duplicate of the already-stored Message. And that `okChar` boolean doesn't need to be there either; you can  just write `if (OnlyChars(value, "Forename"))` right away.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think it is using exceptions for control flow here. It is fairly common to validate data in setters. I am pretty sure I have seen it in .net sources.

Comment: @Andrey in a Form with multiple fields that were entered incorrectly, I believe it is better to show messages for all the bad fields at once, instead of just for the first assignment (not necessarily in form order) that happens to throw an exception.

Comment: What do you mean by your exception is not handled? Most likely you just get exception of different type, not the one (NewException) you expected.

Comment: Note that in your code `throw new NewException(errorMessage);
            forename = null;           `
the second statement will never be executed. Change order.

Comment: Cannot be reproduce with the given code. Must be some kind of stupid error like two different exception types with the same name.

Comment: @Andrey: yes, it's common to validate setters(or input in general). But that should be done before you use the setter. Invalid user input is very common and you can handle that easily without exception. That's not exceptional.

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.100).aspx "It is valid and acceptable to throw exceptions from a property setter." Thought this phrase disappeared from latest revision of the page they explicitly say that exceptions are no-go in getters and nothing about setters so you can assume it is fine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007(v=vs.100).aspx see example about IP address

Comment: @PeterB if form has multiple fields you can loop over them and collect all exceptions and present as a list of errors.

Comment: @Andrey: i know that methods(or properties) should fail fast if it's clear that input is invalid (and it's a bug that you get it). But that doesn't mean that they should contain the business logic and always validate the input if it's a fairly expensive task. Don't confuse pre-check of arguments with implementing business logic with exceptions. Normally the method that assigns the value should validate the input. You would do it twice if the setter also checks it which is ineffective and redundant(you change one logic but the old is still active in the property).

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for you.
I think its issue of namespace

```
using System;
class Player
{
    string forename = "";
    string errorMessage = "";
    public string Forename
    {
        get
        {
            return forename;
        }
        set
        {
            bool okChar = OnlyChars(value, "Forename");

            if (okChar == true)
                forename = value;
            else
            {
                throw new NewException(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool OnlyChars(string value, string p)
    {
        if (value == p)
            return true;
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Err";
            return false;
        }

    }
}

class NewException : Exception
{
    private string messageM;

    public NewException()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public NewException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        messageM = message;
    }

    public string MessageM
    {
        get { return messageM; }
        set { messageM = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var player1 = new Player();
            var player2 = new Player();
            player1.Forename = "asdfg";
            player2.Forename = "qwerty";

        }
        catch (NewException exc)
        {
            bool error = true;
        }
    }
}
```